# Multiply providers in directives Angular2-4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

How to apply both * to string.
I have next code

```
<a class="sidenav-anchor" *ngIf="!item.hasSubItems()" md-list-item md-ripple [routerLink]="[item.route]" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
<md-icon>{{ item.icon }}</md-icon>
<span class="sidenav-item-name fade-in-on-icon-sidenav">{{ item.name }}</span><span fxFlex><!-- fill space --></span>
<span class="badge fade-in-on-icon-sidenav" *ngIf="item.badge" [style.background-color]="item.badgeColor">{{ item.badge }}</span>
</a>
```

and I need apply `*showAuthed="false" to <a>`

showAuthed code

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

import { UserService } from './services/user.service';

@Directive({ selector: '[showAuthed]' })
export class ShowAuthedDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private userService: UserService,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  condition: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.isAuthenticated.subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated) => {
        if (isAuthenticated && this.condition || !isAuthenticated && !this.condition) {
          this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
          this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
      }
    )
  }

  @Input() set showAuthed(condition: boolean) {
    this.condition = condition;
  }

}
```

Code from https://github.com/gothinkster/angular-realworld-example-app & sidebar from http://preview.themeforest.net/item/fury-angular-2-material-design-admin-template/full_screen_preview/19325966?_ga=2.3033968.178803556.1494586718-118953069.1493279302

Comment: What's the problem? What does "both * to string" mean? You can't add two structural directives to the same element.

Comment: What else can be ways to use directives?

Comment: You can use `<ng-container *foo="..."><div *bar></div></ng-container>` to work around this limitation. `<ng-container>` won't be added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Check this way:

```
// <ng-template> for ng4
<template [showAuthed]="false">
<a class="sidenav-anchor" *ngIf="!item.hasSubItems()" md-list-item md-ripple [routerLink]="[item.route]" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
<md-icon>{{ item.icon }}</md-icon>
<span class="sidenav-item-name fade-in-on-icon-sidenav">{{ item.name }}</span><span fxFlex><!-- fill space --></span>
<span class="badge fade-in-on-icon-sidenav" *ngIf="item.badge" [style.background-color]="item.badgeColor">{{ item.badge }}</span>
</a>
</template>
```